# Jquery- disabling 'on change' event handler before it runs

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/B9Fub/

```
<tr class="fis">
Test: <input type="text" name="test" id="test" value="Test">
<tr class="fis">
Empty: <input type="text" name="empty" id="empty">
<input type="button" value="find" id="find">

$('#find').click(function() {
    alert('wont work if any other fields are filled other than TEST'); 
});

$('#test').change(function() {
    // needs to fill the form for other functionality
    $('#empty').val('empty'); 
    alert('change');
});
```

So here I have fields that are filled when the first input is 'changed'

But I don't want it to run [change] if they input in the first field and click the 'find' button.

I was wondering if there was a way to do this. From what I found, 'change' happens before the 'find' button if you click on it.

I've tried changing 'change' to 'focus' and give it to the other field so the first field has no event handlers, but that may give me trouble further down the way.

I need the fields to be filled but I don't want them filled if the user clicks the find button.

Comment: This question is poorly formulated. On one hand you have an alert that shows you only want 'test' to be filled out, then you say the opposite below. Which one is it?

Comment: The find button will work with any field, so I can't erase them. It won't work if multiple fields are filled (it will, but there won't be any results) I also need to keep the fill on change (or anything that can be used to replace 'change')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer. Using e.stopPropagation(); on $('#find') allowed me to stop the .change() from occurring

Answer (score 0):

The `mousedown` event fires before the `change` event, so by using that and jQuery's `data()` method you can set a flag to see if the `activeElement` is in fact `#test` when the find button is clicked, and if so don't set the value :

```
$('#find').on('mousedown', function() {
    $('#test').data('flag', document.activeElement.id === 'test');
});

$('#test').on('change', function() {
    if ( ! $(this).data('flag') ) $('#empty').val('empty'); 
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/B9Fub/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Still, not sure what you want. Maybe this will help.

```
var frm = $('form')[0]; //assuming you have one form on that page
var fnd = $('#find');
fnd.click(function(){
  var te = 0, fe = 0;
  if(frm.elements[0].value !== '')te = 1;
  for(var i=1,l=frm.length; i<l; i++){
    if(frm.elements[i].value !== '')fe = 1;
  }
  if(fe === 1){
    return false;
  }
  else{
    // do your thing here
    return true; // some editors show an error if you don't always return a value
  }
});
$('#test').change(function(){
  if(fnd.val() !== ''){
    return false;
  }
  else{
    // do your thing here
    return true;
  }
});
```